# Integrating GPT-4 with Team Foundation Server for Data Insights

Tags: artificial-intelligence, openai-api, gpt-3, gpt-4, generative

I'm exploring options to integrate GPT-4, the latest version of OpenAI's powerful language model, with Team Foundation Server (TFS). My objective is to leverage GPT-4's capabilities to gain insights from the data stored within our TFS environment.

I'm wondering if there are any APIs or existing integrations available that facilitate this process. Specifically, I'm interested in extracting data from TFS and feeding it into GPT-4 for analysis and generating insights.

Could anyone provide guidance on whether such an API or integration exists? If not, are there any alternative approaches or workarounds that could achieve similar results?

Any advice, resources, or experiences related to integrating GPT-4 with TFS for data analysis and insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried exporting the data from TFS and then feeding the same data to Chat GPT, but exported data doe s not contain all the required details and also exported data is very huge, so it crosses the prompt limit. My expectation is to have an API, which can directly be integrated with TFS server. Like we can integrate 365 copilot with office and GitHub co - pilot with codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct integration between OpenAI's GPT Models and Team Foundation Server, not that I am aware off. But to utilize GPT-4 for gaining insights from TFS data, you would generally need to build a custom integration.

You will use the TFS/Azure Rest API to programatically retrieve the data you are interested in. Then the data will be processed and cleaned so unnecessary data will not be sent to GPT. Once it is done you can send the data to GPT API using gpt-4-0125-preview which has context window of 128000 Tokens can generate output upto 4096 tokens

Comment: yes, and that's where the problem is. The output limit is 4096 tokens. If we want to generate some information from already available historical data, the token limit gets exhausted every time and required output never gets generated.